# Retrofit 2 addQueryParam replacement

Tags: android, http, post, retrofit

In previous retrofit versions it was possible to add an interceptor and use that to add query parameters that were globally needed for example:

```
 .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                        requestFacade.addQueryParam("platform", "android");
                        requestFacade.addQueryParam("app_version", com.package.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);


                }
            })
```

With the new implementation, it's required that you use OkHttpClient.interceptors.  With this new approach, how would one append parameters without removing the original paramaters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an okhttp implementation --

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.httpUrl().newBuilder()
                     .addQueryParameter("platform", "android")
                     .addQueryParameter("app_version", com.package.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                     .build();
        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});
```

Add the client to your retrofit --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://www.example.com")
    .client(client)         
    .build();
```

Comment: This works perfectly for query parameters, thank you so much.  If possible (I can't find the answer anywhere else, and I could make a new stackoverflow question if preferred), how would one append an additional post function from this intercept. For example, if I wanted to add an additional : .addPostField("sUserKey" , "osdjnfj235k2k")  would it be possible from here?

Comment: It is not as straightforward to do. The post parameters have already been converted into a `RequestBody` when the interceptor gets them and there are no methods to manipulate them.  You'll likely have to modify the `RequestBody` yourself by appending the new field.  Probably best to open another question, if no one gets to it, I will take a stab this evening.

Comment: Latest version of retrofit throws UnsupportedOperationException exception

Answer (score 3):

With retrofix 2.3.0 the following code can be used:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException 
    {
        final Request request = chain.request();
        final HttpUrl url = chain.request().url().newBuilder()
             .addQueryParameter("platform", "android")
             .addQueryParameter("app_version", com.package.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
             .build();
        final Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://www.example.com")
    .client(client)         
    .build();
```